# How to programmatically copy/paste in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone, copy-paste

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can the new WP7 cut and paste functionality be used programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904304/can-the-new-wp7-cut-and-paste-functionality-be-used-programatically)

Is there a way to programmatically copy/paste text in windows phone. I want the user to click on a button that should automatically copy some text to the clipboard. The text resides on a TextBlock control (which may be hidden). The only workaround that I have thought of is to pop a dialog with the text filled in in a TextBlock (which natively supports copy paste).

Thoughts?

Answer (score 16):

To set text : `Clipboard.SetText("foo-bar")`

To check if clipboard contains  text : `Clipboard.ContainsText("foo-bar")`

No method to to get text  `Clipboard.GetText()` results in Security Exception